# How is an argument for a callback in React being passed from the child component to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have been working through the React tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html and I am getting through it well enough. I have one thing that I haven't been able to wrap my head around though. Here is the code in full (codepen: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/EmmOqJ?editors=0010):

```
function Square(props) {  
    return (
      <button className="square"
              onClick={props.onClick}>

          {props.value}
      </button>
    );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [  
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];

        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }

    return null;
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
        return (
            <Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}/>  
        );
    }

    render() {  
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  

        this.state = {
            history: [{
                squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            }],
            xIsNext: true,
        };
    }

    handleClick(i) {
        const history = this.state.history;
        const current = history[history.length - 1];
        const squares = current.squares.slice();  

        if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {  
            return;
        }

        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';

        this.setState({
            history: history.concat([{
                squares: squares,
            }]),  
            xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
        });  
    }

    render() {
        const history = this.state.history;
        const current = history[history.length - 1];
        const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

        let status;

        if (winner) {
            status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
        } else {
            status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
        }

        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board  
                        squares={current.squares}
                        onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}  
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="game-info">
                    <div>{status}</div>
                    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the tutorial they pass a callback function `handleClick(i)` from the parent `Game` component to the child `Board` component and from there to the child `Square` component. My question is on how is the argument `i` set? My guess is that the starting point is when `renderSquare(i)` is called in the `Board` component. From there I am lost as to how `i` it makes its way to `handleClick(i)`. Is it stored in the 'onClick`function object passed to`Square`from`Board`?

Comment: I remember struggling with this exact same issue as it's so hard to find the flow of code.

Comment: @SungKim Which resources did you use to wrap your head around the flow of code? Thank you for assistance below?

Comment: After many failures, I ran into [Pure React](https://daveceddia.com/pure-react/) by Dave Ceddia. It makes you write code a lot. That's how I got used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of the flow and origin of the `onClick` function, it is defined in the higher level component Game.

The `Game` component defines the method `onClick` that can be invoked to handle something.

In reverse order,

1. The HTML component [`button`] gives a promise to say, if you give me a
   callback function that matches a said signature, I will call it
   whenever something happens (*clicked in this event*).
2. Now a higher component (parent to button) to the button `Square`
   function, is both interested in

   - using button and
   - interested in being informed when the event happens as per the promise button
     offered in point (1).

But because the Square function itself has no
    real use case for this event, it decided to delegate the handling of
    that event to its parent same way as the button did.

But it goes a step further to say, if you are interested in receiving this notification, my contract is further extended to say, I will only allow notification of the event if and only if you pass in your callback through a member of my input object as `onClick`.

3. So another higher level component `Board` (parent to Square) will
   somehow need to satisfy component `Square` requirements of passing in an object
   with a member `onClick`.  Notice some things though, the `renderSquare` method member of `Board`,

   - Receives as an input argument 'i' that it uses to evaluate something (...) setting the value and `onClick` properties when initiating a new instance of `Square`, and subsequently returning that instance (because JS supports Higher Order Functions [Higher Order Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#JavaScript))
   - It defines an `anonymous function` as a delegate, of which it's implementation is just to return a member of the props called `onClick` (*it will appear that the Board also had a contract with any potential parent that there must be a member onClick that's passed on to it*)...please note that since this syntax is not yet officially adopted, babel is used to transpile these code into something that a typical browser will understand.
   - `renderSquare` method and or Board itself is not doing anything to the onClick member that's been passed around except just returning it in its own anonymous function on     `onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}`

   I assume you know how the result of that statement will look, but for argument's sake it basically becomes 
   `function onClick(){return [this].props.onClick(i);}`

   4. The root component `Game` (`Board` parent), is the one that defines and provides the actual implementation that satisfies the requirements of the `onClick` (*as defined by button component*) method and passes it on as `props` to the child component `Board`. Now it means whenever `Board` has an encounter with the `onClick` specifically from its `props`, it will essentially be accessing the anonymous function defined in `Game` which subsequently returns `Game`'s `handleClick` function see point 3.2 above.

To attempt to answer your question

> My question is on how is the argument i set? My guess is that the
>   starting point is when renderSquare(i) is called in the Board
>   component. From there I am lost as to how i it makes its way to
>   handleClick(i). Is it stored in the 'onClick function object passed
>   toSquarefromBoard`?

The most important thing to notice here is that, all of this code higher up is all blueprint or definitions on how the code will work when active or invoked, think of it a just a pipeline. So the definition does not mean that the `handleClick(i)` is being called right away, infact it is not called up until later when our button component fires the event, when something causes / satisfied button to publish the event, of which when it happens, the reverse of these steps I've just tried to explain happens all the way down until the root Game's `handleClick` function gets invoked.

I realize that my answer could be very long but I hope it paints a message and hopefully helps you to sort of visualize the flow of things.

Answer (score 3):

> My guess is that the starting point is when renderSquare(i) is called in the Board component. From there I am lost as to how i it makes its way to handleClick(i)

You are on the right track.

Within `Board.render()`, `this.renderSquare(...)` is called with a number `1~8`.

And `renderSquare` has an `onClick` handler, `this.props.onClick(i)`.

```js
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
        <Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}/>  
    );
}
```

`this.props` is passed from the parent, `Game.render()`.
So `this.props.onClick` is from `<Board onClick={...} />`

```js
class Game extends React.Component {
    handleClick(i) {
       ...
    }

    render() {
        ...
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board  
                        squares={current.squares}
                        onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}  
                    />
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So `this.props.onClick` matches the `<Board onClick={...} />`
where it's implemented as `(i) => this.handleClick(i)`, in which `this.handleClick(i)` refers to `Game.handleClick(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your guessings were good ! I tried to comment the key aspects of the code on this gist : https://gist.github.com/Sangrene/d6784a855e0e3324e5b499e3a5242c45

Comment: It was helpful to see the explanation alongside the code. JSX is quite the change after spending a lot of time with Python. Do the rules here require the code to be posted along with the link?

Comment: I don't think so, I see a lot of people sharing their codepen or gist on SO answers :)